# Rigged model deforms on one side and doesent on the other

Tags: modeling, rigging

like in the title i've rigged a model with X-Axis mirror so i thought it would be fine, but when i pose the model, it works diffrent on both sides

Here's what i mean:
[image]

Also if it helps, i've used the Human(Meta-rig) armature and adjusted it

There's the file:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: There it is!:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6898" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6898/)

Comment: it's just a basic weight problem, select your armature in Object mode, then your mesh, then switch to Weight Paint mode, select its right arm or forearm, you can see that the influence of each bone is bad, so put the Weight at zero, disable the Front Faces Only option and enable 2D Falloff and paint

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to *Solid* mode. Select your armature and in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Viewport Visibility*, enable *In Front*. Select your mesh and in the *Properties* panel > *Modifiers*, choose the metarig as *Object* of the *Armature* modifier. Select the armature in *Object* mode, then <kbd>shift</kbd> select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode. Select the right upper arm bone, you can see that it influences the forearm mesh, same thing for the forearm bone which affects the upperarm mesh, they should not. So in the 3D View *N* panel > *Tool* tab > *Brush*, choose a *Weight* of zero or a *Blend* > *Subtract*, in the *Options* disable *Front Faces Only* and enable *2D Falloff*, begin to paint until it looks like the left arm.

[image]